# Why $ \sum_{p \leq N \ and \ p \ prime} \frac 1 p $ counts prime factors of $N$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I came across this sum  $ \sum_{p \leq N \ and \ p \ prime} \frac 1 p $ in page 22 of Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik. The authors denote that:

> Incidentally,  this  sum  gives  the  approximate  average  number  of  distinct  prime
> factors  of  a  random  integer  near  N,  **since  about  $1/p$   of  those  integers  are
> divisible  by  p**.

I don't understand the latter part of this sentence at all. I tried a few examples and found it sometimes work (N=12 works while N=49 isn't). Then I searched this sum on google and this site and found nothing related. Can someone give me a more detailed explanation of why it can count prime factors?

Comment: They seem to be talking about Erdos-Kac. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem    as well as Merten's adjacent material. In Hardy and Wright, this is Theorem 430; in the fifth edition this is pag 355. The needed sum is Thm 427, page 351

Comment: Meanwhile, I recommend Kac, Statistical independence in probability, analysis, and number theory.  I have a copy here somewhere.   https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kac2.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for your recommendation. I read some of them and kind of figured this out in an intuitive way. The probability of 2 divisible by n is 1/2 because n is neither odd or even. The probability of 3 divisible by n is 1/3 because n is neither 3k, 3k+1 or 3k+2 where k is an integer. The probability of 4 divisible by n is 1/4 because n is neither 4k, 4k+1, 4k+2 or 4k+3...... so $1/p$ in this sum is the probability of p divisible by N. Then those $1/p$ are being summed up so it is close to the prime factor count of N.

Comment: My original thought is even more naive. A grid like this flashed in my mind:

ReeReeRee
ReeReeRee
ReeReeRee

where R means a red block and e means an empty block. Any block in this grid will be inside a "Ree" group and obviously the possibility of this block being R is 1/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition is something like this:

If $p$ is a prime then there are $\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\rfloor$ numbers between $1$ and $N$ that are multiples of $p$. So a randomly selected number from that range has a $\frac{1}{N}\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\rfloor \approx \frac{1}{p}$ chance of being divisible by $p$.

If there are $n$ primes $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n \leq N$, then for a number $k$ we can define the indicator variables $\delta_{i, k}$ to be equal to $1$ if $k$ is a multiple of $p_i$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $P_k = \sum \delta_{i, k}$ is the count of how many distinct prime factors $k$ has.

So then the average number of prime factors of all the numbers between $1$ and $N$ is the expected value of $P_k$ if we randomly choose $k$. But the expectation of a sum is the sum of the individual expectations, meaning that the expected value of $P_k$ is $\sum E(\delta_{i, k}) = \sum \frac{1}{N}\lfloor\frac{N}{p_i}\rfloor \approx \sum \frac{1}{p_i}$.

The quality of the approximation is going to depend on how much value is lost when rounding $\frac{N}{p_i}$ to an integer - when $N$ is small this will be pretty variable, but once it gets big then you're not going to care too much if $58384928.9$ gets rounded to $58384928$.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful explanation! It really helped me understand the topic.